# datastax opscenter Unable to find a matching cluster for node with IP

Tags: opscenter, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to configure a new OpsCenter 5.2.2 manually to a newly launched and running Cassandra Cluster 2.0.17, so I add a cluster conf file, start the OpsCenter, which then creates the CF OpsCenter, all fine. When I start the datastax agent on the first node I get this:

`2015-10-29 17:25:11+0100 []  WARN: Unable to find a matching cluster for node with IP d1r1n1; the message was [u'5.2.2', u'/2122343799/conf']`. This usually indicates that an OpsCenter agent is still running on an old node that was decommissioned or is part of a cluster that OpsCenter is no longer monitoring.

Seems the agent is trying to push data to OpsCenter which then in turn doesn't recognize a cluster holding this node. But why what maybe I be missing?

Just defined my cluster in `/etc/opscenter/cluster/cluster.conf`:

```
[jmx]
port = 8081

[kerberos_client_principals]

[kerberos]

[agents]

[kerberos_hostnames]

[kerberos_services]

[cassandra]
api_port = 9161
seed_hosts = d1r1n1,d1r1n2,d1r1n3,d1r1n4
conf_location = /etc/cassandra/blob.conf/cassandra.yaml
log_location = /var/log/cassandra/blob-system.log

[storage_cassandra]
api_port = 9161
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to create a cluster.conf file it gets created for you.

Comment: I know if you use the UI, but I don't as I run two datastax agents on different ports against each their cassandra instance on the same server, I preferred to configure it manually. Both clusters are running fine, and both agents too and the both seems try and send data back to opscenter only both gets this error. How do a agent identify it's node/hostname/id for metrics collected and how does opscenter try to match such IDs against a cluster definition and where would this be stored?